# Insert data into table with select query with other values

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I want to add another value (the date) into my table

I am using the below query but it doesn't work

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (user_id, work_id, d_date)
((SELECT user_id, work_id FROM user INNER JOIN work WHERE user.user_name = ? AND work.work_id = ?), ?)';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table (user_id, work_id, d_date)
        SELECT user_id, work_id, ?               
        FROM user 
        INNER JOIN work 
        WHERE user.user_name = ?
          AND work.work_id = ?';
```

In the parameters block you must put the date to be inserted then username then work id which must be used for filtering.

Comment: the d_date is input from the user not from the table.

Comment: @preterMX00 No difference. Simply check that you provide the parameters values to the query in correct order. And do not forget to check the value provided by user carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide another values like you are selecting from your select statement. Put also those values in your field set, like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (user, function, role, date, category) 
SELECT user, 118, 'dev', DATE(NOW()), 1 
FROM users where function= 62;
```